# jquery POST twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, getusermedia

Please can somebody enlighten me as to why this is submitting a POST request twice? NB: There is a delay of approximately 2 minutes before the second request is sent (exact same data).

The code uses GetUserMedia() to display user webcam feed, and immediately copies a snapshot to a canvas. It then gets a data url, before using jquery to POST it to the server. The issue I am experiencing is that a second post request is being executed with the same data around two minutes after the first. I cannot, for the life of me, figure out the cause of the issue - please help!

```js
// The width and height of the captured photo. We will set the
// width to the value defined here, but the height will be
// calculated based on the aspect ratio of the input stream.
var width = 320;    // We will scale the photo width to this
var height = 0;     // This will be computed based on the input stream
// |streaming| indicates whether or not we're currently streaming
// video from the camera. Obviously, we start at false.
var streaming = false;
// The various HTML elements we need to configure or control. These
// will be set by the startup() function.
var video = null;
var canvas = null;
var track = null;
var video = document.getElementById('video');
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var photo = document.getElementById('photo');
var kill = null;
// get feed
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false })
  .then(function (stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    track = stream.getTracks()[0];  // if only one media track
    video.play();
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
  });

video.addEventListener('canplay', function (ev) {    // when recieving stream

  if (kill === null) {

    if (!streaming) {
      height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);
      if (isNaN(height)) {    // // Firefox currently has a bug
        height = width / (4 / 3);
      }
      video.setAttribute('width', width);    // make sure video and canvas html is correct size
      video.setAttribute('height', height);
      canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
      canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
      streaming = true;
      ev.preventDefault();
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (width && height) {
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);
        //  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        $.post('/recv', {
          img: canvas.toDataURL()
        });
        track.stop();
        kill = 1;
        ev.target.removeEventListener(ev.type, arguments.callee);
        return false;
        //  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      }
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>webrtc snapper</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="camera">
        <video id="video"></video>
    </div>
    <canvas id="canvas">
    </canvas>
    <div class="output">
        <img id="photo">
    </div>
    <script src="capture.js">
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It could be that you need to add `Promise` to your functions as you are setting up your listener before finishing to run the `getUserMedia()` function. Therefore your listener function runs once and again when done executing `getUserMedia()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Please can you specify the changes suggested as I'm not quite sure what you mean. the GUM api call is complete before the event listener is added to 'video'... I'm new to js, I've probably done something ridiculous.

Comment: Put your event listener inside the `then` of `getUserMedia`.

Comment: Doesn't make any difference...

Comment: Is it just the commented area that's being called twice or is it more like the entire addEventListener is being run twice?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. FYI I cloned the code from thew github associated with [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos), so it should be pretty good. It turns out that even when i revert to the original code with the only change being the jquery post being added, it's still sends twice.

Comment: What happens if you use the event `loadedmetadata` instead of `canplay` ?

Comment: the issue is the .POST... Doesn't matter what's sent, it is always duplicated :/

Comment: Logically this could only happen if `canplay` has a duplicate bind, it's being triggered again (prior to the unbind), or if the entire page is called again. The code that's shown does not show either of those situations, so it's likely elsewhere in the codebase. Using Chrome dev tools inspect the `video` element, click the "Event Listeners" tab, and see what's binding to `canplay`.

Comment: This is the entire code base at the moment, besides a simple expressjs back end to recieve what's xhr'd to /recv... I checked the chrome dev tools and there's nothing showing on the event listeners tab.
One thing that may be useful information, is that immediately after the second request to '/recv', a error message is shown on the chrome console, that reads "jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:3000/recv net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Answer (score -3, accepted):

## I solved the issue by having the server respond with a 200 OK,

after receiving the POST. It seems that I had forgotten to add this and it was causing JQUERY to repost (or something similar, because the post section of express was being called twice.)

Thank you for your responses.

Answer (score 0):

The `canplay` event is a tricky one, it can play more then once, for example, when the current time is changed the browser needs to load more data either from cache or the network. This can trigger the canplay event.

In order to solve it, there are two ways.

**One** - as the answer above me stated, is to use a flag.
I do not support this, as getting mixed with flags can sophisticate your code and make it hard to read and hard to maintain.

**Second** - is to unsubscribe from the event:

```
video.bind('canplay', function (ev) {
   // your logic ....
   video.unbind('canplay')
}
```

**From jquery 3.0 and on**:

```
 video.on('canplay', function (ev) {
       // your logic ....
       video.off('canplay')
    }
```

The above code is cleaner, easier to read and to maintain.

In the end, it falls for your judgment what best suits your needs here.

Comment: Thanks for your response: Before I posted here I made the same conclusion, so it's good to see that we're on the same page. I implemented the flag suggestion, because it seemed like the quickest option for somebody like me with such limited JS knowledge. Please see the 'kill' variable - have I implemented it incorrectly?
Thanks :)

Comment: Okay I added "      video.removeEventListener('canplay', function(){return}); " on the line following the .POST   and I'm still experiencing the same duplication issue. ('off' and 'unbind' couldn't be applied - I think this is because video wasn't selected using jquery... I figure removeeventlistener does the same job?...)

Comment: Yes, it will to the job, try it :)

Comment: It's in the above code already as 
ev.target.removeEventListener(ev.type, arguments.callee);
The problem was on my server. Thanks for your posting, though.